# What parameter types does ForAllMembers function accept?

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to learn AutoMapper. I have this legacy class which I don't understand how it works. I have researched internet but can't find anything on for example what is `op` argument passed to `ForMember` or the argument `x` passed to the `ForAllMembers`. Is there any doc that describes those methods and the type of parameters they accept?

```
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
    {
        // mappings between model and entity objects
        public AutoMapperProfile()
        {
            
            CreateMap<AccountRequest, Account>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Schedules, op => op.Ignore())
            .ForMember(d => d.UserFunctions, op => op.Ignore())
                .ForAllMembers(x => x.Condition(
                    (src, dest, prop) =>
                    {
                        // ignore null & empty string properties - with exception of PhoneNumber
                        if (prop == null && x.DestinationMember.Name != "PhoneNumber") return false;
                        if ((x.DestinationMember.Name != "PhoneNumber") && (prop.GetType() == typeof(string)) && string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)prop)) return false;

                        // ignore null role
                        if (x.DestinationMember.Name == "Role" && src.Role == null) return false;

                        return true;
                    }
                ));
                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In most IDEs you can hover over the variable or function to see its type (return type) or can do  ctrl+ left mouse button click on it opens the defenition of variable, class, function and etc. try to do so

Comment: Did you check the AutoMapper [documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/)? The best place to start with any library is its documentation and [Getting Started](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html) or QuickStart projects. Automapper docs are searchable, and searching for ForAllMembers returns a section in the [Custom Resolvers](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html?highlight=forallmembers#resolvers-and-conditions) page

Comment: The single argument is an `Action<IMemberConfigurationExpression>` but that doesn't explain much. AutoMapper was built to allow mapping by convention, based on names and certain other common-sense conventions. For more complex mappings it's possible to specify custom mappings and custom ways of deciding which property/type maps to what. `ForAllMembers` can apply customizations to all members. In this case it's applying a `Condition` that only maps specific only maps specific properties

Comment: Thanks everybody. It gives me some start